# @media print not printing properly

Tags: html, css

I have some big web forms that I'm trying to print. They get cut off pretty bad when printed.

I have added a `@media` print in my stylesheet.

for the big forms, I've assigned a specific `class` name so that I can recognize it in my css, mainly:

```
<div id="divFormMain" class="customPrint2" style="margin:5px;">
```

and this is what I'm trying to do in CSS:

```
.customPrint2 {
    -ms-transform: scale(.9); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: scale(.9); /* Safari 3-8 */
    transform: scale(.9);

}
```

Unfortunately transform doesn't do the job and it still gets cut off.

and last thing I would like to add in there is

```
@page size:landscape
```

However, I do not want to print in landscape for all forms, only for `customPrint2`

Is there a way to do this?

```
@page {
 margin:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm !important;
}

@media print {
#divFrameContent  {
    height:100% !important;
    width:100% !important;
    border:none !important;
    table-layout:fixed !important;
}
.FormMenuNavigation {
    display:none !important;
    height:0px !important;
}
#tblBodyContent {
    /*table-layout:fixed !important;*/
}
#divFormContent {
    width:98%;
}

.customPrint {
    -ms-transform: scale(.9); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: scale(.9); /* Safari 3-8 */
    transform: scale(.9);
}

.customPrint2 {
    -ms-transform: scale(.9); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: scale(.9); /* Safari 3-8 */
    transform: scale(.9);

}

}
```

Comment: Please show the entire `@media print` that (I assume) surrounds the `customPrint2` block.

Comment: @PeterB updated

Comment: @PeterB - alternatively If i was able to transform it somehow to be able to fit everything in a page that would work too.But as you can see i set the margins to 0, and if I transform:scale(.75), it makes the content much smaller, but the margins look very big (left & right). I wish it would transform the content only, and still have it at my page margins, which are 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try the following code...It works fine for me...May be u should set some dimensions for your page to be printed...

```
@media print {
  @page {
    size: 330mm 427mm;
    margin: 14mm;
  }
  .container {
    width: 1170px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following. It will apply to all sub elements.

```
.customPrint * {
        transform: scale(0.9);
    }
```

Comment: In that case, you will need custom css for the printing forms; i.e. font-size, family, etc. Scale was a shortcut to make it easier.